# I want my file path to work for linux and Windows environment using Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, environment

I am writing a java code to create work space directory to check-in single or multiple files. File name/s are received from jsp page
Below is the code snippet for directory and file path creation.

```
try {
        File uploadedFile = null;
        String tmpDir = context.createWorkspace();
        String filePath = tmpDir + java.io.File.separator;
        //System.out.println("filePath"+ filePath);
        //String filePath1 = tmpDir + java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(File.separator);
        //System.out.println("filePath1 "+ filePath1);
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setRepository(new File(tmpDir));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        HashMap hmRequest = new HashMap();
        String sFileName = DomainConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        String sParamKey = DomainConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        String sParamValue = DomainConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        StringBuffer fileNameList = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer nameList = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer uploadfileNameList = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer uploadnameList = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer coverletterfileNameList = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer coverletternameList = new StringBuffer();

        if (null != items && items.size() > 0) 
        {
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) 
            {
                FileItem item = iter.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) 
                {
                    sParamKey = item.getFieldName();
                    sParamValue = item.getString();
                    hmRequest.put(sParamKey, sParamValue);
                }
            }

            Iterator<FileItem> iter1 = items.iterator();
            while (iter1.hasNext()) 
            {
                FileItem item1 = iter1.next();
                if (!item1.isFormField()) 
                {
                    //String sFileName1=null;
                    sFileName = item1.getName();
                    String fieldname = item1.getFieldName();
                    if (UIUtil.isNotNullAndNotEmpty(sFileName) && fieldname.equals("coverLetterFile")) 
                    {
                        sFileName = sFileName.substring(sFileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                        sFileName = 
                        System.out.println("sFileName"+ sFileName);
                        //sFileName1 = sFileName.substring(sFileName.lastIndexOf(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(File.separator)) + 1);
                        //System.out.println("sFileName1111"+ sFileName1);
                        uploadedFile = new File(tmpDir + File.separator + sFileName);
                        item1.write(uploadedFile);
                        coverletterfileNameList.append(tmpDir + File.separator + sFileName);
                        coverletterfileNameList.append(",");
                        coverletternameList.append(sFileName);
                        coverletternameList.append(",");
                    }
```

Whether below line create a problem in linux environment as I am working on Windows. Can any body please suggest a solution for this?

sFileName = sFileName.substring(sFileName.lastIndexOf("\") + 1);

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.separator`, which fills in the correct separator for your system environment, instead of the hardcoded string.

Answer (score 0):

use `File.separator` **eg:** `FileName = sFileName.substring(sFileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);`

`java.io.File` class contains,
`File.separator`: Platform dependent default name-separator character as String. **For windows, it's '\' and for unix it's '/'.**

Comment: Thank you for the details. I am using above suggested option and is working

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can use `File.separator` instead of the hardcoded String to get the index.

But if you can I would suggest using [Java Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead (available since Java 1.7 in the NIO api)

The `Path` class provides custom operations to perform actions over a system path and automatically manages the separators.

I give an example of usage, but you can google it to see more:

```
    Path myPath = Paths.get(root, "subFolder", "fileName");
    System.out.println("My path: " + myPath.toString());
    Path file = myPath.getFileName();
    System.out.println("My file: " + file.toString());
```

As you can see, it's very simple.
In this case, root  will be the file path you get from the jsp. You can construct the path with aditional folders (or just the one you received)

With the root path `"C:/tempFolder"` the output would be:

On Windows:

```
"My path: C:\tempFolder\subFolder\fileName"
"My file: fileName"
```

On Linux and Mac:

```
"My path: /tempFolder/subFolder/fileName"
"My file: fileName"
```